# Port specified when running node is undefined

Tags: node.js, environment-variables

The port is specified when i ran the node project says undefined.

```
> sf-chain@1.0.0 dev E:\System\dev\node\sf-chain
> nodemon ./app "HTTP_PORT=3002" "P2P_PORT=5002" "PEERS=ws://localhost:5001"

[nodemon] 1.18.3
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node ./app HTTP_PORT=3002 P2P_PORT=5002 PEERS=ws://localhost:5001`
process.env.HTTP_PORT :: undefined
HTTP_PORT :: 3001
Listening for peer-to-peer connections on: 5001
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3001
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1045:20)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1259:14)
    at listen (net.js:1295:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1391:5)
    at EventEmitter.listen (E:\System\dev\node\sf-chain\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:618:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\System\dev\node\sf-chain\app\index.js:28:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I ran the first instance using

```
npm run dev
```

const HTTP_PORT = process.env.HTTP_PORT || 3001;

The application starts successfully running on port 3001 since i didn't specify HTTP_PORT at the run command.
But when trying to run another instance by specifying HTTP_PORT using the below command

`npm run dev HTTP_PORT=3002 P2P_PORT=5002 PEERS=ws://localhost:5001`

I get this error.

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3001
```

Which means the HTTP_PORT specified at run time is seen as undefined that's why it's trying to using the 3001 port for the first instance.

Comment: This is specific to `dev` script and whatever it runs. They weren't shown.

Answer (score 0):

> **Error: listen EADDRINUSE** 
>   - error comes when somthing is already running/listen on that port

Its because sometime instance of same nodejs acquire port and didnt kill/exit the process properly,

if you have Ubuntu check first which process is using port by

```
lsof -i :3001 // Port no.
```

then output will be some thing  like this.

```
COMMAND  PID       USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
node    2496 nasiruddin   13u  IPv6  37696      0t0  TCP *:3001 (LISTEN)
```

kill using **PID**

```
kill 2496
```

then start again

Comment: In the code, I have `const HTTP_PORT = process.env.HTTP_PORT || 3001;` which means if the HTTP_PORT is not specified at the point of starting the application, it should use 3001 for the port. But I specified HTTP_PORT at the command for running the second instance but HTTP_PORT environment variable sees the port specified as `undefined`.